# How to get access to global state from mutation namespace module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my `state` I have two namespace modules: `portfolio` and `stocks` like this:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    stocks,
    portfolio
  }
})
```

In `stocks` I have `stocks` property and in `portfolio` I have `funds` property. I want to commit `BUY_STOCK` mutation, which needs access to `stocks` from `stocks` module and `funds` from `profile`. I set it in `profile` module as follows:

```js
"BUY_STOCK"(state, {stockId, quantity, stockPrice}) {
  console.log(state.stocks.stocks, state.portfolio.funds)
}
```

I got `undefined`. That's because `state` is just a local module state. How can I get access to global state from this mutation?

Comment: Don't think you can directly access state from another module. You can either set the states you need from multiple modules as rootState, or create mutations and getters and then access and manipulate the module level states via getters and mutations.

Answer (score 0):

You can access rootState from  vuex actions context. Instead of calling the mutation you can call an action:

```
actions: {
 buyStock(context, {stockId, quantity, stockPrice}) {
    console.log(context.state.funds) // access local state
    console.log(context.rootState.stocks.stocks) // access stocks state through rootState
    // Then call mutations with the retrieved values 
    context.commit("BUY_STOCK", {stockData, portfolioData}) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, got it, but how I gan change this state?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't **import** the `profile` module to the store/index.js,
so it would look like this:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    stocks,
    portfolio,
    profile
  }
})
```

And you should probably consider using getters in each module:

portifolio.js

```js
export default {
  state: {
    funds: 'Some funds'
  },
  getters: {
    funds(state) {
      return state.funds
    }
  }
}
```

stocks.js

```js
export default {
  state: {
    stocks: 'Some stocks'
  },
  getters: {
    stocks(state) {
      return state.stocks
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can access them from the `profile` module like so:

profile.js

```js
export default {
  actions: {
    BUY_STOCK({ getters }, { stockId, quantity, stockPrice }) {
      console.log(getters.funds, getters.stocks)
    }
  }
}
```